# Repopulating cascading dropdowns on refresh/back navigation w/ autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Some browsers support autocomplete on forms by default.  So when refreshing a page that has been partially (or fully) completed, the browser will retain the field values.

My problem is that when I have cascading dropdowns, like so:

> Select your car:
>   * Make dropdown
>   * Model dropdown
>   * Year dropdown

...and the user refreshes or comes back to this form from another page, the first one is populated (as it's not dependent on any other values), the next two are empty, because these are populated on change of the previous dropdowns.

I figured out how to repopulate the Model, as it's just a matter of detecting a value for the Make and calling the Ajax to repopulate model.

However, since the browser tries to set the value on Model before I have it repopulated, I lose the original value.

Is there a way in javascript to capture the previously selected values when the page is loaded, so that I can properly repopulate these cascading dropdowns?

Comment: If the browser is already retaining that information when reloading but your JavaScript changes those values, you could check to see if those values are populated before repopulating everything, and simply not repopulate.

Comment: Well, the problem is the browser isn't automatically repopulating the cascading dropdowns.  Those come back as blank, but all other fields are populated (textboxes, etc.).  I need to repopulate the dropdowns, so that the autocomplete can fill those in.  The problem is, the autocompolete happens before I can repopulate.  So those ultimately remain blank.

Comment: I think the safer way would be to deactivate this default behavior and set the values explicitly, e.g. by storing and retrieving them from a cookie.